Xdtool doesn´t work with crontab
I have this command in crontab:
09 23 * * * xdotool mousemove 344 484 click 1
But with screen locked it doesn't work: could you kindly help me how to solve? Thanks

XY problem. What is your actual goal?

It won't work, as cron jobs run in a separate environment from your X session. You need at least set the DISPLAY variable in the cron job.

Could you suggest the complete command? Thanks

I tried this 09 23 * * * DISPLAY=:0 xdotool mousemove 344 484 click 1 but wiht no success. It doesn't work with screen locked
